# Copy Specific Cells from sheet2sheet to the next blank row

Tags: vba, excel

My prob is I want to be able to copy specific cell values from different source worksheets (i.e. PRICES1 & PRICES2 & more) to the first empty row in another worksheet (TOTALS).
The code so far does the job BUT if for example PRICES1 runs and leaves a blank cell in column R then when PRICES2 is evoked all the cell values will occupy the next available line except for value "B10" which will occupy the blank cell of the previous row in column R.

So, my question is this: Is there a way I can force all the cell values to occupy the same row even if there are some blank cells in the previous row? For example can I force the rest of the values to occupy the same row (in the appropriate cells of course) as B4 & C4 values?

```
Sub PRICES1_click()
ActiveSheet.Calculate
ActiveSheet.Columns("F:F").AutoFit

If Sheets("TOTALS").Range("M" & Rows.Count).End(3)(2).Value = "" Then

    If Sheets("TOTALS").Range("M" & Rows.Count).End(3)(2).Value = "" Then
    Sheets("TOTALS").Range("M" & Rows.Count).End(3)(2).Value = Sheets("PRICES1").Range("B4").Value
    Sheets("TOTALS").Range("N" & Rows.Count).End(3)(2).Value = Sheets("PRICES1").Range("C4").Value
    Sheets("TOTALS").Range("O" & Rows.Count).End(3)(2).Value = Sheets("PRICES1").Range("B6").Value
    Sheets("TOTALS").Range("S" & Rows.Count).End(3)(2).Value = Sheets("PRICES1").Range("L46").Value
End If

End If

Worksheets("TOTALS").Calculate
End Sub


Sub PRICES2_click()
ActiveSheet.Calculate
ActiveSheet.Columns("F:F").AutoFit

If Sheets("TOTALS").Range("M" & Rows.Count).End(3)(2).Value = "" Then

    If Sheets("TOTALS").Range("M" & Rows.Count).End(3)(2).Value = "" Then
    Sheets("TOTALS").Range("M" & Rows.Count).End(3)(2).Value = Sheets("PRICES2").Range("B4").Value
    Sheets("TOTALS").Range("N" & Rows.Count).End(3)(2).Value = Sheets("PRICES2").Range("C4").Value
    Sheets("TOTALS").Range("O" & Rows.Count).End(3)(2).Value = Sheets("PRICES2").Range("B6").Value
    Sheets("TOTALS").Range("R" & Rows.Count).End(3)(2).Value = Sheets("PRICES2").Range("B10").Value
    Sheets("TOTALS").Range("S" & Rows.Count).End(3)(2).Value = Sheets("PRICES2").Range("L46").Value
End If
End If


Worksheets("TOTALS").Calculate
End Sub
```

You can find the excel file at:
[sendspace attached excel file](http://www.sendspace.com/file/2dxfrr)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set the destination row into a variable and use that instead. Pick a column that you know will always be populated.

```
Dim rowNo As Long

rowNo = Sheets("TOTALS").Range("M" & Rows.Count).End(XlUp).Row + 1


Sheets("TOTALS").Range("M" & rowNo).Value = Sheets("PRICES2").Range("B4").Value
Sheets("TOTALS").Range("N" & rowNo).Value = Sheets("PRICES2").Range("C4").Value
Sheets("TOTALS").Range("O" & rowNo).Value = Sheets("PRICES2").Range("B6").Value
```

etc.

Comment: Ok, I'm fairly new to vba so I'm not sure I implemented the variable correctly (I get a type mismatch)... Where am I posibly wrong?

Comment: Can you try it again. I missed `.Row` from the end. Sorry about that.

Comment: I think that DOES work! Thanks very much man! MUCH obliged! I hope I won't have to bother you again ;-)